# New column based on multiple line conditions

Tags: r, multiple-conditions

I have this df

```
data.frame(Name = c("AI147", "AI147", "AI147", "AI147", "AI147", 
                         "AI20", "AI20", "AI87", "AI88", "AI88", "AI88", "AI65", "AI65"),
                         Presence1 = c("both_type1", "soil", "soil", "water", "both_type2", 
                         "soil", "water", "both_type2", "soil", "soil", "soil", "water", 
                         "water"))
```

I want to create a conditional column (Final) based on the data for each Name. (1) If a given Name has more than 1 type of presence, or only presence "both_type1" or "both_type2", than Final = both, (2) if a given Name has only presence "soil", than Final = soil, (3) if a given Name has only presence "water", than Final = water, so that the table looks like this

```
data.frame(Name = c("AI147", "AI147", "AI147", "AI147", "AI147", 
                         "AI20", "AI20", "AI87", "AI88", "AI88", "AI88", "AI65", "AI65"),
                         Presence1 = c("both_type1", "soil", "soil", "water", "both_type2", 
                         "soil", "water", "both_type2", "soil", "soil", "soil", "water", 
                         "water"),
                         Final = c("both", "both", "both", "both", "both", "both", 
                         "both", "both", "soil", "soil", "soil", "water", "water"))
```

I've tried several ways that I've found here on the site but none came close to doing it that way.

Answer (score 3):

We can create a condition with `n_distinct` or using `str_detect` i.e. after grouping by 'Name' if 'Presence1' contains `any` 'both' substring or having more than one unique value (`n_distinct`), then return 'both' or else return the value of 'Presence1'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df %>%
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    mutate(Final = case_when(any(str_detect(Presence1, 
       "both")|n_distinct(Presence1) > 1) ~ 'both',
        TRUE ~ Presence1 )) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 13 x 3
   Name  Presence1  Final
   <chr> <chr>      <chr>
 1 AI147 both_type1 both 
 2 AI147 soil       both 
 3 AI147 soil       both 
 4 AI147 water      both 
 5 AI147 both_type2 both 
 6 AI20  soil       both 
 7 AI20  water      both 
 8 AI87  both_type2 both 
 9 AI88  soil       soil 
10 AI88  soil       soil 
11 AI88  soil       soil 
12 AI65  water      water
13 AI65  water      water
```